# Linq Full Outer Join Error

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I am connected to the Adventure Works 2012 database using Linqpad as shown below:

[image]

I am trying to write a full outer join.  My research tells me it should look like this (as shown in the screenshot):

```
var LeftOuterJoin =  from p in Products
join pv in ProductVendors on p.ProductID equals pv.ProductID into ppv
from pv in ppv.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {ProductName = p.Name};

var RightOuterJoin =  from v in Vendors
join pv in ProductVendors on v.BusinessEntityID equals pv.BusinessEntityID into ppv
from pv in ppv.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {VendorName = v.Name};

LeftOuterJoin.Union(RightOuterJoin);
```

However, the error in the screenshot (see screenshot) is:

```
'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Union<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<AnonymousType#2>'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: (LeftOuterJoin.toList()).Union(RightOuterJoin.toList());

Comment: @Viplock, the error I get with this is: 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'toList' and no extension method 'toList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#2>' does not contain a definition for 'toList' and no extension method 'toList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#2>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: as i can see , there is type issue , both anonymous type have different property , so that may be causing the issue for using `Union` . you can create a common type with same property and use it. or have both property and use according to query.

Comment: The anonymous types produced by the 2 `select` statements are not equivalent. Make sure both contain `string ProductName, string VendorName` for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i can see , there is type issue , both anonymous type have different property , so that will be causing the issue for using Union . you can create a common type with same property and use it. or have both property and use according to query Like:

```
var LeftOuterJoin =  from p in Products
join pv in ProductVendors on p.ProductID equals pv.ProductID into ppv
from pv in ppv.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {VendorName = "",
            ProductName = p.Name,};

var RightOuterJoin =  from v in Vendors
join pv in ProductVendors on v.BusinessEntityID equals pv.BusinessEntityID into ppv
from pv in ppv.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {VendorName = v.Name,
            ProductName = "",};

var result = LeftOuterJoin.Union(RightOuterJoin).ToList(); // force execution to get results.
```

use this if you are using LinqPad

```
var result = LeftOuterJoin.Union(RightOuterJoin)
result .Dump();
```

This will work for you.

Comment: Thanks.  The query runs, however it returns no results.  The corresponding SQL query returns hundreds of results.

Comment: does your separate linq queries returning the data properly, first check if the linq queries are correct?, and check the sql query created by sql profiler

Comment: yes.  The two queries run as expected independently.  I think it is the variable declarations that is causing the issue.  Should this be a C# Statement in Linqpad?

Comment: try using `LeftOuterJoin.Concat(RightOuterJoin)`

Comment: I think it is the variable declarations.  The two queries run independently without the variable declarations.  No results are returned when they are run independently with the variable declarations.

Comment: I have answered my own question.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 for providing a partial answer.  I appear to of downvoted this answer by mistake.  Please amend the question so that I can upvote it (let me know once you have edited it).

Comment: `fullOuterJoin.Dump();` line is just used to fetch the data , because till then you will only collect the query in the variable, or if you iterate by any chance , it will automatically fetch the data.As you will know that the query written will only contain the query , not the data.

Comment: Viplock, please add: fullOuterJoin.Dump(); as the last line.